# macOS sandboxed app, cannot copy file inside desktop folder to temporary directory

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, appstore-sandbox

I have a native macOS app, Messer, which allows to convert/resize/pad image files. One feature I built into it is auto-converting files in a specific folder.

This feature works well on most folders, even though it might require permissions to access them. For example, selecting the `Downloads` folder to auto-convert triggers a permission dialog for the user to grant access.

The same goes for the `Desktop` folder, however, even if the permission has been granted on the `Desktop` folder, I'm getting an error when trying to copy a file inside a sub-directory.

The error output:

```
2022-04-27 13:35:04.255243+0200 Messer[1254:11983] open on /Users/osp/Desktop/posts/a-plus-content-4.png: Operation not permitted
Messer, could not copy file Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“a-plus-content-4.png” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “com.ospfranco.messer”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/osp/Desktop/posts/a-plus-content-4.png, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
), NSDestinationFilePath=/var/folders/qn/vyvn49j90jv9_77vq77wzvw00000gn/T/com.ospfranco.messer/a-plus-content-4.png, NSFilePath=/Users/osp/Desktop/posts/a-plus-content-4.png, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000206dda0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

Which is thrown when I try to copy the file to the temporary directory:

```swift
func secureCopyItem(at srcURL: URL, to dstURL: URL) {
    do {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dstURL.path) {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dstURL)
        }
            
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: srcURL, to: dstURL)
    } catch let error {
        print("Messer, could not copy file \(error)")
        SentrySDK.capture(error: error)
    }
}
```

Here you can see the app has full disk access:

[image]

Yet the app still crashes! If I choose any other folder the copy operation works normally. All the entitlements and permissions seem to be there. Any idea what could be wrong?

EDIT 1:

It seems it's not quite clear I'm **really** copying from a desktop URL to a temporary directory, so here is some of the surrounding code:

```swift
if url.isImage && url.isLocalFile {
    let newFileUrl = FileConstants.tempUrl.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
                
    FileManager.default.secureCopyItem(at: url, to: newFileUrl)
                
    self.initPipeline(urls: [newFileUrl], autoSave: true)
}
```

The temp URL in a different constants file:

```swift
static let tempUrl: URL = {
    return FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
}()
```

I can promise you this same code run with another file in another directory (e.g. Downloads) is correct and works without any error.

Edit 2:

After reading a bit some other answers, it could be a problem with how I'm accessing the resource, I allow the user to select a folder via UI and then save this path in my application. However, due to permissions, it could be that the resource is only accessible for a period of time after the user has selected the folder and not indefinitely. So after some time when I try to access the resources in the folder, macOS simply blocks any of my attempts to read the files.

I have tried using some resource lock method and it returns false on the passed URL:

```swift
let scopedResourceLocked = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                print("SCOPED RESOURCE LOCKEd \(scopedResourceLocked)") // prints false
                let newFileUrl = FileConstants.tempUrl.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
                
                FileManager.default.secureCopyItem(at: url, to: newFileUrl)
                
                url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

Edit 3:

I just tried reselecting the folder (via NSOpenPanel) and converting a file and it worked. So I guess there is no way to achieve this in a consistent manner without user interaction. After a while macOS will lock/protect the files in the folder again.

Comment: It seems to me that an understanding of the issue would depend upon knowing what `srcURL` and `dstURL` _are_.

Comment: You can see the destination and source URLs in the error output, trying to copy from desktop folder to temporary directory. the same function works well when trying to copy a file in a different directory.

Comment: Your destination path doesn't point to the Desktop folder as you claim, so the issue is probably not with the posted code.

Comment: Also I don't understand why you get permission dialogs if you have full disk access.

Comment: I'm trying to copy a file FROM the desktop to the temporary directory, not the other way around. The error somehow complains about the temporary directory not having permissions, but when I copy other files not in the desktop it works just fine.

Comment: I get the permissions dialogs the first time the app runs. I granted full disk access manually.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve] that actually behaves in this problematic way?

Comment: And maybe change the title/description so it's clear you are copying to a temporary folder. Is the Desktop folder local or on an iCloud Drive?

Comment: I can try to create one, but I'm short on time, for now, I just wanted to check if anyone has faced the issue as is.

Comment: The desktop folder is local.

Comment: In a sandboxed app you need a Security Scoped Bookmark to access locations outside the container permanently (created once with a user selected URL via NSOpenPanel)  regardless of Full Disk Access.

Comment: I think you are right vadian, I found this https://developapa.com/security-scoped-bookmark/ seems that is the correct way when allowing users to select a random folder on their computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @vadian for pointing me in the right direction. As it turns out, having full disk access is not enough, even if the user has given permission to a specific folder.

Once you get the URL from NSOpenPanel, you need to create a Bookmark and save the binary data. On further app openings you hydrate the binary data. From this bookmark object you can create a URL again, on which you need to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` and `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource` to access any previous folder the user has granted access to (even if you are accessing a file or subfolder inside of that folder.

Basically followed this tutorial:

https://medium.com/fantageek/how-to-access-bookmark-url-in-macos-b38bc82f03e9

Here is a visual version:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Delete sandbox capability on project settings and file saves.